# How to find out size of crawled webpage in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am learning [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).
I want to find out size of crawled webpage or size of response in KB or MB etc using Scrapy.
I can find out length of content of crawled webpage using`response.body`
what is the simplest way to findout how much data is getting downloaded per `request`?

I tried to understand [this solution](http://snipplr.com/view/66993/avoid-downloading-pages-which-exceed-a-certain-size/) which is similar to my my requirement. but I am not able to understand this code.

```
parse(self, response):
    url=response.url
    content=response.body
    #download_size=
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get size by using information provided by reading content-length from headers property of [Response Object](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response).

```
parse(self, response):
    url=response.url
    content=response.body
    #response length in bytes
    download_size= int(response.headers['content-length'])
```

Comment: there is no key in headers named contend-length so I am getting `exceptions.KeyError: 'Content-Length'`

Comment: in my case value of `response.headers` is `{'Content-Language': ['en'], 'Set-Cookie': ['JSESSIONID=F55063B0C8DB599B39FF8B15945A1AD8-n1.MBAPP12; Domain=.something.com; Path=/', 'citySpecialSessionCookie=noGeoCityFirstTimeUser; Path=/'], 'Vary': ['Accept-Encoding'], 'Server': ['Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.8.8'], 'Cache-Control': ['max-age=0, no-cache'], 'Date': ['Mon, 21 Apr 2014 09:00:05 GMT'], 'Content-Type': ['text/html;charset=UTF-8'], 'X-Mod-Pagespeed': ['1.4.26.3-3101']}
`

Comment: ok.. that means content length is not being sent. You can do `download_size = len(response.body)`

Comment: `len(response.body)` would give you the size after decompression, so wouldn't measure the amount of data transferred.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the built in response.body and apply len on it.
Simply do

```
size=str(len(response.body)),
```